# html5 offline storage for Windows Mobile 6.1 or an alternative?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, html, pocketpc

I understand that there are no browsers currently which support offline storage for mobile 6.1.

I am trying to find a web form based solution avoiding the loss of data when my device has no connectivity. Have ruled out Gears and would like to avoid a win forms application as the forms change so often. Are there any other approaches that I should look at which are viable in C#?

Are there any estimated dates for when we might see a browser for mobile 6.1 which can offer offline storage?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know very much about HTML5 compliant browsers for Windows Mobile.

[Opera Mobile or Mini](http://my.opera.com/ODIN/blog/opera-mobile-10-for-nokia-n900-n800-n810-maemo-standards-support) don't support offline HTML5 features.

[Skyfire](http://www.skyfire.com/product/skyfire-1-5-for-windows/) is a browser based on Webkit, but no information is present on what kind of HTML5 features it supports.

Today the real offline storage support for Windows Mobile **is not HTML5 compliant** and is [Google Gears](http://code.google.com/intl/fr/apis/gears/mobile.html).